# chrome extension redirect to listing page with refreshed content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have created reminder app which allows user to create , edit and delete reminder but i am facing one problem here , when i click on add button after that i want to redirect it into listing page , just like we do in normal website how can i resolve it ? i have created following page for my chrome extension

1. Listing page
2. Add Page
3. Edit Page

i have tried following code to redirect page but it opens 2 window. so it is not feasible for me.
acknowledge me as soon as possible.

```
function redirect(){
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
  'bounds': {
 'width': 600,
  'height': 550
},
"resizable": true
 });
}
```

and i have also tried to call ShowAllEvents(); 
function which lists all reminders but it doesn't list currently added reminder.

Comment: Why can't you use `location.href = 'some_new_url.html'`?

Comment: @wOxxOm it does't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change chrome app window location, but not from main.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875410/change-chrome-app-window-location-but-not-from-main-js)

Comment: @wOxxOm no my question is totaly different i am able to redirect it but the problem is , not with refreshed content (or reminder) after redirection it only shows me old records instead of that i want all records including one we just created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have called following function on storage event changed and now its coming with refreshed content

```
  chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes,areaName)
  {
   var event = document.getElementById('event_show');
   event.click();
  });
```